# online leaderboard for xna + windows phone game

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xna, leaderboard

In my xna + WP7 game i have local score, looking for online leaderboard/API to submit the user score. Any links or source would help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is mogade lib that provides a decent interface. I even ported it to windows 8. Will send you a link in a bit (you can find source on github)

I found this post even before i wrote a single line of code for my game
http://briansolli.wordpress.com/2011/03/30/online-leaderboard-for-your-wp7-game/

you can mogade code here 
https://github.com/mogade